# CSS problem, 100% width keeps moving out of position

Tags: css, dynamic, width

I'm currently working on this website,
http://no-illusions.nl
It's going fine but I found a pretty stupid thing that I can't resolve.

I have an div (wrapper) with an width of 500px and inside I have different div's containing images and text. Now the problem is that the text is dynamic in width, on some parts it could be 200px width and on some pages it could be 350px.

So I put the width on 100% but now the part just floats underneath where I want it!

This is how it should look,
![how it should look][1]

But this is how it looks,

I hope you guys can give me a push in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that relative sizes are relative to the containing element. If you say `width: 50%`, you'll get an element that's 1/2 the width of its container. So your saying `width: 100%` makes the text div take 100% of the container's width, and it becomes 500px as well.

You can put the image inside the text div and float it. With appropriate margins/padding, the text will wrap around the image, and you'd get something like:

```
imgimgimg   text text text 
imgimgimg   text text text
imgimgimg   text text text

text text text text text
text text text text text
```

The basic html structure woul be:

```
<div style="width: 500px;">
    <div style="float: left; margin: 5px;"><img src="..."></div>
    text text text text text
</div>
```

otherwise you'd need to go with fixed with divs, and dynamically change the text div's width based on whether there's an image present or not. `if (has image) { width: 350} else { width: 500}` type of thing.

Comment: It seems like that last option is the best solution. Pfff.

Comment: Thanks, I revisited that part of the site and thought a way to fix it. Apperently I was a bit too losse with the float:left on some elements. Removing them and it floated right in there :).

Answer (score 0):

This has troubled me before and I usually solve it by setting the paragraph's max-width. That should cause the text to wrap within that width.

Comment: Well that kind of destroys the idear of dynamic content since the with of the element is variable.

Comment: Yes, but I mean a max-width. As in, if it gets to that width, wrap content. If not, let it be. Though from your other answers it seems this doesn't help a lot. Sorry.

Comment: I found the solution! Or the problem, whatever you want to call it. Problem was that a few elements had an float:left, removing and playing with that and suddenly it popped in right there!

Comment: That's great. Floating is very tricky, thanks for coming back with your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
.update_respond p{width: 273px;}
```

Comment: Yes (i've tried that) but that also effects the text element for the div underneath causing it to be to small.

Comment: then try using <TABLE> - http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/tables/ - width every sizing and positioning possibilities

Answer (score 0):

You can set a max-width of 330px on your .update_respond class.

Comment: Yes (i've tried that) but that also effects the text element for the div underneath causing it to be to small.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any width at all for `<p>`-tags, as they are block-elements, which are strechted to the maximum width available.

Comment: Maximum width of their parant element is a better way to describe it?

Comment: Not in every case, as there may be floats, whose width is subtracted from the parents-width.